# Replace sensitive IP addresses in Wireshark with XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX

Tags: networking, tcpip, wireshark

What would be an easy way to replace a sensitive IP address in a Wireshark packet capture with XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX? When I export the pcap in txt or csv I can no longer import it into Wireshark.

Answer (score 0):

When running a Linux box, you could perform a

```
sed -i 's/10.10./XX.XX./g' <file name>
```

where 10.10. are the first two octets of your IP address and  is the name of the capture log.

Under Windows you could run an advanced editor and use the search and replace feature.

Comment: this seems to corrupt the capture. I can only see about 700 out of the 1500+ lines in my capture after running this. Any ideas?

Comment: Does your package capture file contain any binary data? If yes, try strings <filename> |sed -i 's/10.10./XX.XX./g' -